# How do i shift this ul component to above?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i shift this block to a little upward. I want this carousel to import in my Project which is a multipage. Which is a container

So this code is from my project actual code snippet for the carousel is
https://codepen.io/mohit-04/pen/abWPwPq

i want to reduce the above space. Code when it comes to my project looks like
[image: Carousel in my project]

```
<!-- Carousel -->
        <div class="container my-2">
          <div class="main-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="margin-check">
                <h2 class="text-center my-2">Carousel</h2>
                
                <%- include('./mohit/carousel') %>
              </div>
     </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

where as carousel file is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/carousel.css" />
<div class="slide hi-slide">
  <div class="hi-prev"></div>
  <div class="hi-next"></div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="card">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523275335684-37898b6baf30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body space">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="140px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600080972464-8e5f35f63d08?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mjh8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572635196237-14b3f281503f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542291026-7eec264c27ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564466809058-bf4114d55352?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjJ8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br /><br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546868871-7041f2a55e12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTZ8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="150px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581235720704-06d3acfcb36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
          alt="Img 1"
          height="90px"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p><br /><br /><br /></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/script.js"></script>
<script>
  (function ($) {
    var slide = function (ele, options) {
      var $ele = $(ele);

      var setting = {
        speed: 1000,

        interval: 10000,
      };

      $.extend(true, setting, options);

      var states = [
        {
          $zIndex: 1,
          width: 120,
          height: 150,
          top: 69,
          left: 134,
          $opacity: 1,
        },
        {
          $zIndex: 2,
          width: 130,
          height: 170,
          top: 59,
          left: 0,
          $opacity: 0.1,
        },
        {
          $zIndex: 3,
          width: 170,
          height: 218,
          top: 35,
          left: 110,
          $opacity: 1,
        },
        { $zIndex: 4, width: 250, height: 300, top: 0, left: 263, $opacity: 1 },
        {
          $zIndex: 3,
          width: 170,
          height: 218,
          top: 35,
          left: 470,
          $opacity: 1,
        },
        {
          $zIndex: 2,
          width: 130,
          height: 170,
          top: 59,
          left: 620,
          $opacity: 1,
        },
        {
          $zIndex: 1,
          width: 120,
          height: 150,
          top: 69,
          left: 500,
          $opacity: 1,
        },
      ];

      var $lis = $ele.find("li");
      var timer = null;

      $ele.find(".hi-next").on("click", function () {
        next();
      });
      $ele.find(".hi-prev").on("click", function () {
        states.push(states.shift());
        move();
      });
      $ele.on("mouseenter", function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
      });
      // .on("mouseleave", function () {
      //   autoPlay();
      // });

      move();
      autoPlay();

      function move() {
        $lis.each(function (index, element) {
          var state = states[index];
          $(element)
            .css("zIndex", state.$zIndex)
            .finish()
            .animate(state, setting.speed)
            .find("img")
            .css("opacity", state.$opacity);
        });
      }

      function next() {
        states.unshift(states.pop());
        move();
      }

      function autoPlay() {
        timer = setInterval(next, setting.interval);
      }
    };

    $.fn.hiSlide = function (options) {
      $(this).each(function (index, ele) {
        slide(ele, options);
      });

      return this;
    };
  })(jQuery);

  $(".slide").hiSlide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div container `<div class="slide hi-slide">` has 115 top margin, just reduce this value or use relative margin size(%, viewport, rem).

[image]

Comment: yes it work. But i have one more problem regarding this. That is the container is still same means when i bring the carousel above the container too shrink as you can see that in above pircture. I want the that the container should enclose the given items. But the items means carousel is overflowing.

Comment: it's because carts(<li>) use px, try to use relative units